# python with php & ajax

Tags: php, jquery, python, ajax

I have this script on my **php** file:

```
<script>
var lokasi="bandung";
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_location.php',
        data:{'location' : lokasi},
        success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    }
        })
</script>
```

and the **ajax** file:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="root";
$db_name="db_urllib";
$db_connect=mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
$db_select=mysql_select_db($db_name,$db_connect);
$query=mysql_query("insert into table values('$_REQUEST[location]')");
if($query)echo "Ok";
else echo "No";
```

It's working when I run it with my browser, but I want to run it with python.

Is there a way to run it with python?

Comment: You want to run a php script in python?  Have you considered running with php cli?

Comment: Your script is TOTALLY INSECURE.  You are not sanitizing $_REQUEST['location'].  It would be trivial to perform SQL injection.  mysql_* functions are DEPRECATED -use mysqli instead.  at least use `mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['location'])`, _please_.

Comment: If I could up-vote your comment 10000 times I would @DanFarrell

Comment: it's just a test program, the real program is more complex and more secure. And i have tried with urllib2 but the ajax part is not working